# WP_Query meta_query argument

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to write a 'complex' WP_Query but it keeps failing. The meta_query argument Im using is:

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
    "relation" => "AND",
        array("relation" => "OR", 
            array(
                'key' => '_htp_hide_trending_posts',
                'value' => 'on',
                'type' => 'CHAR',
                'compare' => '!='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_htp_hide_trending_posts',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'views',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    );
```

`_htp_hide_trending_posts` is a custom meta_value. If I ignore the views part and just use the OR statement, it's ok but adding the ADD relation and it then ignores the OR relation search. I need both as it needs to order by views and that doesn't work if it's not in the meta_query. I'm going round in circles, hoping someone can spot an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out a solution:

```
$query_args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key' => '_htp_hide_trending_posts',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        );
        $query_args['meta_key'] = 'views';
        $query_args['meta_compare'] = '>';
        $query_args['meta_value'] = '0';
        $query_args['orderby'] = array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC');
```

I didn't need the OR query which seemed to do the trick.